# How to convert numbers or characters to MathML format?

Tags: javascript, mathml, mathtype

Sample examples,

```
yes -> <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mi>y</mi><mi>e</mi><mi>s</mi></math>
99  -> <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mn>99</mn></math>
```

For those given inputs, I would like to get the corresponding mathml expressions. I'm doing this because `mathtype.setMathML(99)` won't work, it should be `mathtype.setMathML(<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mn>99</mn></math>)`
I'm using [mathtype_web](https://docs.wiris.com/en/mathtype/mathtype_web/start).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<mtext>` comes into the rescue. we can use it to render either numbers or characters.

```
mathtype.setMathML(<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mtext>{NUMBER or CHARACTERS}</mtext></math>)
```